# imported Css loading issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and I am able to link css files to view.But imported css files I am not able to link ,Can you guys help me how to link without using ../ 
eg.)style.css I can link

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="theme" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css"/>
```

but inside style.css,I have some css like these

```
@import "jquery/jquery-ui.min.css";
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "summernote/summernote.css";
```

Can You guys help me how to link..

Comment: is `css/style.css` file being loaded???

Comment: Yes.It is loading..

Comment: and are all files in same folder i.e. `css/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css` etc...

Comment: yes..everything inside css folder..

Answer (score 0):

You can do two thing.Edit your css file like this

```
@import "css/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css";
@import "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css";
@import "css/summernote/summernote.css";
```

Or keep all the file where your main index.php file belongs(keep them outside css folder).Because Your File path is related with your main folder where main index.php belongs.